# filter() function not working within the for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

I wrote the code below

```
miRNA.list <- c("let-7a-5p", "let-7a-1-3p", "let-7b-5p")
summary.df <- data.frame()
for (miRNA in miRNA.list) {
  
  temp.name <- miRNA
  
  temp.df <- df.mirna.pv %>%
              filter(`temp.name` == "yes") %>%
              summarise(downregulated = sum(str_count(status, "downregulated")),
                        upregulated = sum(str_count(status, "upregulated")),
                        all = n())
  
  summary.df <- rbind(summary.df, temp.df)
  
}
```

to filter the following dataframe based on the "let-xxx" columns and then count number of up or downregulated genes;

```
print(df.mirna.pv)

          let-7a-5p    let-7a-1-3p   let-7b-5p            status
Xkr4          no            yes          no               upregulated
Mrpl15        yes           yes          no               downregulated
Lypla1        yes           yes          yes              downregulated 
Tcea1         no            yes          no               not significant
```

However, for some reason, it cannot match the names in miRNA list with the column names, or at least I think this is the problem, as this is my output:

```
downregulated upregulated all
1             0           0   0
2             0           0   0
3             0           0   0
4             0           0   0
5             0           0   0
6             0           0   0
```

Any ideas what could be happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: Please avoid loops if using tidyverse unless you are doing simulations. Otherwise there are functions in tidyverse/data.table that will perform the task more efficiently

Answer (score 1):

You could make a `factor` out of the `"status"`. Then just loop over the `"miRNA.list"` columns in an `sapply`: first equal to `"yes"`, then `table` the positive statuses and `c`oncatenate the `sum`.

```
> df.mirna.pv$status <- as.factor(df.mirna.pv$status)
> t(sapply(df.mirna.pv[miRNA.list], \(x) {
+   y <- x == 'yes'
+   c(table(df.mirna.pv$status[y]), all=sum(y))[-2]
+ }))
            downregulated upregulated all
let-7a-5p               2           0   2
let-7a-1-3p             2           1   4
let-7b-5p               1           0   1
```

BTW, if you just need boolean for `miRNA.list`, you could do

```
> (miRNA.list <- startsWith(names(df.mirna.pv), 'let'))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> (miRNA.list <- grepl('^let', names(df.mirna.pv)))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

or for the values

```
> (miRNA.list <- grep('^let', names(df.mirna.pv), value=TRUE))
[1] "let-7a-5p"   "let-7a-1-3p" "let-7b-5p"
```

Works all in the code, and might avoid some typing.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df.mirna.pv)
structure(list(`let-7a-5p` = c("no", "yes", "yes", "no"), `let-7a-1-3p` = c("yes", 
"yes", "yes", "yes"), `let-7b-5p` = c("no", "no", "yes", "no"
), status = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("downregulated", 
"not significant", "upregulated"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("Xkr4", 
"Mrpl15", "Lypla1", "Tcea1"), class = "data.frame")
> dput(miRNA.list)
c("let-7a-5p", "let-7a-1-3p", "let-7b-5p")
```

Comment: I like the use of *`c`oncatenate* :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix your for-loop, you need to pass `!!sym(temp.name)` to `dplyr::filter()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df.mirna.pv <- structure(list("let-7a-5p" = c("no", "yes", "yes", "no"), 
                       "let-7a-1-3p" = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"), 
                       "let-7b-5p" = c("no", "no", "yes", "no"), 
                       status = c("upregulated", "downregulated",
                                  "downregulated", "not significant")), 
                  row.names = c("Xkr4", "Mrpl15", "Lypla1", "Tcea1"), 
                  class = "data.frame")

miRNA.list <- c("let-7a-5p", "let-7a-1-3p", "let-7b-5p")
summary.df <- data.frame()
for (miRNA in miRNA.list) {
  
  temp.name <- miRNA
  
  temp.df <- df.mirna.pv %>%
    filter(!!sym(temp.name) == "yes") %>%
    summarise(downregulated = sum(str_count(status, "downregulated")),
              upregulated = sum(str_count(status, "upregulated")),
              all = n())
  
  summary.df <- rbind(summary.df, temp.df)
  
}

summary.df %>% mutate(name = miRNA.list, .before = 1)

#>          name downregulated upregulated all
#> 1   let-7a-5p             2           0   2
#> 2 let-7a-1-3p             2           1   4
#> 3   let-7b-5p             1           0   1
```

but we can do this easily with `tidyr::pivot_longer()`:

```
df.mirna.pv %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-status) %>% 
  filter(value == "yes") %>% 
  summarise(name = first(name), 
            downregulated = sum(status == "downregulated"),
            upregulated = sum(status == "upregulated"),
            all = n(),
            .by = name)
```

or if we want to absolutely avoid hard-coding:

```
df.mirna.pv %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-status, 
                      values_transform = list(value = ~`==`(.x, "yes"))) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = status, 
                     values_from = value, values_fn = sum) %>% 
  janitor::adorn_totals("col") # %>% select(-`not significant`)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing normal and programmatic use of `dplyr`. Namely, `` filter(`temp.name` == "yes") `` is looking for a column named `"temp.name"`, not a column that is indirectly referenced in the local variable `temp.name`.

I think this may be what you want?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tmp <- pivot_longer(quux, cols = -status)
filter(tmp, value == "yes") |>
  count(name, status) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = status, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) |>
  left_join(count(tmp, name, name = "all"), by = "name")
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#   name        downregulated `not significant` upregulated   all
#   <chr>               <int>             <int>       <int> <int>
# 1 let-7a-1-3p             2                 1           1     4
# 2 let-7a-5p               2                 0           0     4
# 3 let-7b-5p               1                 0           0     4
```

You can remove `` `not significant` `` if you don't need it.

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list("let-7a-5p" = c("no", "yes", "yes", "no"), "let-7a-1-3p" = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"), "let-7b-5p" = c("no", "no", "yes", "no"), status = c("upregulated", "downregulated", "downregulated", "not significant")), row.names = c("Xkr4", "Mrpl15", "Lypla1", "Tcea1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer r2evans, and I will keep in mind the iterations formatting. Script already altered!

Unfortunately your solution isn't giving the right result, as it isn't counting the ocurrences of up or downregulated per column.

Comment: Just adding here that your solution helped me. After creating the longer df, I did:

```
tmp %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(value == "yes") %>% summarise(downregulated = sum(str_count(status, "downregulated")),
                                                                upregulated = sum(str_count(status, "upregulated")),
                                                                all = n())
```

Thanks!

Comment: See my edit, @MauricioOliveira. Perhaps you could edit your original question to specify what your expected values are?